# Error: Annotator "sentiment" requires annotator "binarized_trees"

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, pos-tagger

Could any one help me when this error can happen. Any idea is really appreciated. Do I need to add anything, any annotator. Is this an issues with the data or the model that i am passing apart from default model.

i am using Standford NLP 3.4.1 to do the sentiment calculation for social media data. When i run it through spark/scala job i am getting this following error for some data.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "sentiment" requires annotator "binarized_trees"
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:300)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
    at com.pipeline.sentiment.NonTwitterSentimentAndThemeProcessorAction$.create(NonTwitterTextEnrichmentComponent.scala:142)
    at com.pipeline.sentiment.NonTwitterTextEnrichmentInitialized.action$lzycompute(NonTwitterTextEnrichmentComponent.scala:52)
    at com.pipeline.sentiment.NonTwitterTextEnrichmentInitialized.action(NonTwitterTextEnrichmentComponent.scala:50)
    at com.pipeline.sentiment.NonTwitterTextEnrichmentInitialized.action(NonTwitterTextEnrichmentComponent.scala:49)
```

here is the code i have in scala

```
 def create(features: Seq[String] = Seq("tokenize", "ssplit", "pos","parse","sentiment")): TwitterSentimentAndThemeAction = {
      println("comes inside the TwitterSentimentAndThemeProcessorAction create method")
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("annotators", features.mkString(", "))
      props.put(""pos.model", "tagger/gate-EN-twitter.model");
      props.put("parse.model", "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz");
      val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you run this code on 1 machine and 1 thread?

Comment: Nope I am running it on hadoop/spark with 200 partition

Comment: Huh; I thought sentiment only required the parse annotator. What happens if you add in a BinarizerAnnotator explicitly? I.e., add `binarizer` to the annotators, and the following to the properties: `props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.binarizer", "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.BinarizerAnnotator")`

Comment: Thanks gabor.I have added like this props.put("pos.model", "tagger/gate-EN-twitter.model")
      props.put("parse.model", "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz");
      props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.binarizer", "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.BinarizerAnnotator") but no luck and its giving the same error. i was using the default PCFG parser and then swith to shift reduce parser with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413885/nlp-sentiment-processing-for-junk-data-takes-time. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

...Are you sure this is the error you get? With your code, I get an error

`Loading parser from serialized file tagger/englishSR.ser.gz ...edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL`

This makes much more sense. The shift reduce parser models lives at `edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz`. If I don't use the shift reduce model, the code as written works fine for me; likewise if I include the model path above it works ok.

The exact code I tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec scala -J-mx4g "$0" "$@"
!#

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline._
import java.util._

val props = new Properties()
props.put("annotators", Seq("tokenize", "ssplit", "pos","parse","sentiment").mkString(", "))
props.put("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

Comment: Gabor,thanks for looking into it.I have downloaded the compatible 3.4.1 model englishSR.ser.gz and put it in the tagger directory.For normal scenario I am not seeing the error. i am getting this error when I run with spark/hadoop with over 200 partition

Comment: I suspect this is a configuration error with your Spark cluster then. I'm not I'm qualified to help there though...